# Increment of multiple file prefixes?

Tags: bash, sh

I am looking for a way in Bash to rename my file prefixes.
These files are all in one folder. No other files will be in it.

```
00 - Artist - Title.mp3
01 - Artist - Title.mp3
```

... and so on

to

```
01 - Artist - Title.mp3
02 - Artist - Title.mp3
```

... and so on

The prefix can also be only a single (0, 1, 2, ...), double(00, 01, 02, ...), triple, ... prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -we 'for (@ARGV) {
              my ($n, $r) = /^([0-9]+)(.*)/;
              rename $_, sprintf("%0" . length($n) . "d", 1 + $n) . $r;
          }' *.mp3
```

The regular expression match extracts the number to $n and the rest to $r.
$n + 1 is then formatted by [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf) to be zero padded, having the same length as the original number.

Note that it changes the length of the number for 9, 99, etc.

Comment: Well great that works. I was hoping for Bash. In Perl to define the directory, would that be defined in for('/directory..') { ?

Comment: @Sebastian: What do you mean by "define the directory"?

Comment: Let's say I add this command to my bash file. I want to run the perl-command you posted on a specific directory. Where can I tell this for-loop to do it for example /home/media/

Comment: @Sebastian: `cd` to the directory before running the script.

Answer (score 0):

It's risky business, but it here's a sh solution that seems to work:

```
ls *.mp3 | sort -rn | while read f
do 
    number=`echo "$f" | sed 's/ .*//'`
    rest=`echo "$f" | sed 's/^[^ ]* //'`

    number2=`expr $number + 1`
    number2f=`printf %02d $number2`

    mv -i "$number $rest" "$number2f $rest"
done
```

`sort -rn` so that it won't try to overwrite anything if there are adjacently-numbered files with the same artist and title (which probably won't happen, although it does if I take your example literally).

`mv -i` so it will ask you before it overwrites anything if there are any of those cases that manage to come up anyway.

If you have a cleaner way you like to break things like `$f` up into `$number` and `$rest`, be my guest.